# Moving in a Text Adventure Game

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm working on a simple text adventure project. When I run the code it won't work when I try to input right/left/forward/backwards twice. It resets to the beginning of the game.

Also, when I input any input out of order of these if statements, like forward and then a left, the program goes to my fail-safe. I have asked this question before and someone replied stating I should use the if else in my code. What other alternatives could I use for this project?

The fail-safe also doesn't work. I type in an approved direction but the fail-safe continues indefinitely.

```
Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
int x, y;
x = 0;
y = 0;
String gameStart = "c";
String direction = "c";

System.out.print("Welcome to my text adventure game!\nIf you want to play, type in 'Start'");
gameStart = key.next();

while(!"Start".equals(gameStart))
{
  System.out.print("Incorrect input.  Type in 'Start' to begin:  ");
  gameStart = key.next();
}

while(gameStart.equals("Start"))
{
  direction = "";
  x = 0;
  y = 0;
  System.out.println("");
  System.out.print("You wake up in an extremly small room.  You estimate it to be a perfectly sized 3x3 room.  Based on your estimation, your in the center of the room.  Dispite that there is a bed directly behind you, you wake up on a circular rug.  Weird, but, the door's right in front of you.  Time to escape!\nYou can move forward, backwards, left and right.");
  direction = key.next();

  if(direction.equals("right") || direction.equals("Right"))
  {
    x++;
    System.out.print("You walk to the right.");
    direction = key.next();
  }

  else if (direction.equals("left") || direction.equals("Left"))
  {
    x--;
    System.out.print("You walk to the left.");
    direction = key.next();
  }

  else if (direction.equals("forward") || direction.equals("Forward"))
  {
    y++;
    System.out.print("You walk Forward.");
    direction = key.next();
  }

  else if (direction.equals("backwards") || direction.equals("Backwards"))
  {
    y--;
    System.out.print("You walk backwards.");
    direction = key.next();
  }
  else 
  {
    do
    {
    System.out.print("Sorry, you can't do that.  Try again:");
    direction = key.next();
    }
    while(!direction.equals("right")|| !direction.equals("Right") || !direction.equals("left") || !direction.equals("Left") || !direction.equals("forward") || !direction.equals("Forward") || !direction.equals("backwards") || !direction.equals("Backwards"));
  }

while(gameStart.equals("Start"))
  {
    if (x<-2 || x>2 || y<-2 || y>2)
    {
      System.out.println("ERROR:  OUT OF BOUNDS");
      System.exit(0);
    }
    if (x==-2 || x==2)
    {
      System.out.println("You try to walk further, however, you run right into a wall.");
      x--;
    }
    if (y==-3 || y==3)
    {
      System.out.println("You try to walk further, however, you run right into a wall.");
      y--;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you replace `key.next()` with `key.nextLine()`

Answer (score 0):

You have a semicolon after your while loop, which makes it end right away.

> ```
> while(gameStart.equals("Start"));
> ```

Also, quite a few bad practices in this code, like:

- Comparing to a literal string instead of a constant
- Initializing variables to some random value, just leave them as nulls
- Storing your gameStart logic as a string, when it makes more sense to be a boolean
- You have two equals check when you can use .ToLower() or case incensitive Equals()

There's many more things to critique, but I guess you are just starting out :)

Answer (score 0):

In this section

```
if (x==-2 || x==2)
{
  System.out.println("You try to walk further, however, you run right into a wall.");
  x--;
}
```

You you do a x-- even when x is already -2 and at the boundary of allowed (min) value. If x would be -2, it would become -3 and call system exit in the first if(). I'd put the validation of getting near the boundary even before updating the values.